# Button click not behaving the same as page load

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, button, gridview

**Situation:**

I have a mostly working aspx page that contains an asp:GridView with an asp:TextBox using an asp:RangeValidator to manage the gridview's pagesize.  I also have two asp:LinkButton's to increment the sizing up and down respectively. In the codebehind, I am using a datatable as the gridview's datasource.

After first getting multiple rows populated into the gridview, I am then able to update the rowcount textbox, press enter which results in the gridview showing the new page size (via the pageLoad event).

**Issue:**

When I click either linkbutton to adjust the rowcount textbox value and then update the gridview's pagesize, the gridview is shown blank afterwards ... like there's no data available.

After the rowcount was updated via a linkbutton click and the gridview is shown blank, I can then click in the rowcount textbox and press enter and the gridview is now displayed having it's pagesize match the rowcount textbox value.  This suggests that gridview data is still present and not missing.

**Research**

Via debugging I can see the pageload event fires before the linkbutton click events, but I don't understand why the gridview doesn't display after the linkbutton click execution. In the codebehind, the gridview is being re-binded after setting the pagesize at the loadpage and linkbutton click events.

**What I need help with**

I'm not sure how to correct this behavior so that the linkbutton click event correctly updates and displays the gridview to match the pagesize requested.

I don't want to hack the page lifecycle.  Any normal aspx lifecycle suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**HTML snippet**

Note: I've removed some html content and all css styling to make the relevant html elements easier to read.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SearchForEmployee.aspx.vb" Inherits="EmployeeSearch.SearchForEmployee1" EnableSessionState="True" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

...

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
...

<label>Row Count: <asp:TextBox ID="RowCount" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="7" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox></label>
&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="BtnRowCountUp" runat="server" ClientIDMode ="Static"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></asp:LinkButton>
&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="BtnRowCountDown" runat="server" ClientIDMode ="Static"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></asp:LinkButton>
<br /><asp:RangeValidator ID="RowCountValidator" Type="Integer" MinimumValue="5" MaximumValue="20" ControlToValidate="RowCount" runat="server"></asp:RangeValidator>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ClientIDMode="Static" PageSize="7">

...

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CodeBehind snippet**

```
Public Class SearchForEmployee1
  Private dt As DataTable
  Private cRowCountMin As Integer = 5
  Private cRowCountMax As Integer = 20
  Private cRowCountInit As Integer = 7


  Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
      If Not Session("dt") Is Nothing Then
          dt = DirectCast(Session("dt"), DataTable)
      End If

      ...

      If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
          Me.RowCountValidator.MinimumValue = cRowCountMin.ToString
          Me.RowCountValidator.MaximumValue = cRowCountMax.ToString
          Me.RowCount.Text = cRowCountInit.ToString
      End If
  End Sub

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
          ...  
      End If

      Me.GridView1.PageSize = CInt(Me.RowCount.Text)
      Me.GridView1.DataBind()

  End Sub

  Private Sub BtnRowCountUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRowCountUp.Click
      Dim iRowCount As Integer = CInt(Me.RowCount.Text)
      If iRowCount < cRowCountMax Then
          iRowCount += 1
          Me.RowCount.Text = iRowCount.ToString
          Me.GridView1.PageSize = iRowCount
          Me.GridView1.DataBind()
      End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub BtnRowCountDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRowCountDown.Click
      Dim iRowCount As Integer = CInt(Me.RowCount.Text)
      If iRowCount > cRowCountMin Then
          iRowCount -= 1
          Me.RowCount.Text = iRowCount.ToString
          Me.GridView1.PageSize = iRowCount
          Me.GridView1.DataBind()
      End If
  End Sub
 
  Protected Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
    ...

    '
    '  Fill datatable
    '

    ...
    
    Session("dt") = dt

  End Sub  

  ...

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It just dawned on me what i didn't try ... and it worked!

The solution was to re-apply the session value for the datatable before re-binding the gridview. I thought that the init page execution was sufficient to re-initialize the datatable variable, but it wasn't.  It also needed to be done on the button click events.

**Updated codebehind:**

```
    Private Sub BtnRowCountUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRowCountUp.Click
        Dim iRowCount As Integer = CInt(Me.RowCount.Text)
        If iRowCount < cRowCountMax Then
            iRowCount += 1
            Me.RowCount.Text = iRowCount.ToString
            Me.GridView1.PageSize = iRowCount

            If Not Session("dt") Is Nothing Then
                dt = DirectCast(Session("dt"), DataTable)
                Me.GridView1.DataSource = dt
            End If

            Me.GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRowCountDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRowCountDown.Click
        Dim iRowCount As Integer = CInt(Me.RowCount.Text)
        If iRowCount > cRowCountMin Then
            iRowCount -= 1
            Me.RowCount.Text = iRowCount.ToString
            Me.GridView1.PageSize = iRowCount

            If Not Session("dt") Is Nothing Then
                dt = DirectCast(Session("dt"), DataTable)
                Me.GridView1.DataSource = dt
            End If

            Me.GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I would have moved your init code to the on-load event. If IsPostback = false, then load the grid first time, shove table  into session. On additonal postbacks, then you grab session to the table. It not clear why init event was used, but I find using on-load works much better. Anyway, it looks like you ok now anyway. You never actually really have to test for the existing session value if you set it in first load postback = false, and thus any additonal actions on page - the else of the postack (true) on first line of code will pull session back to the table.